# Join two tables where second table is used as a reference for multiple columns of the first table

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have two tables (names are fictitious for this example):

```
---------------------------------------
               MainTable
---------------------------------------
Condition_1 | Condition_2 | Condition_3
---------------------------------------
    J       |      H      |     N
    R       |      T      |     
    I       |             |     
    W       |      T      |     
    R       |      M      |     Q

...and so on...


--------------------------------------
              Conditions
--------------------------------------
Condition_Code | Condition_Description
--------------------------------------
      A        | Description goes here
      B        | Description goes here
      C        | Description goes here
      D        | Description goes here
      E        | Description goes here
      F        | Description goes here
      G        | Description goes here

...and so on...
```

I'd like to be able to query a `DataSet` that would have the `Condition_Description` from the `Conditions` table as the value of each condition that has a code within the `MainTable` table.

So that when I look at a specific row:

```
ds.Tables["Query"].Rows[i]["Condition_1"].ToString();
```

I would either get an empty string or a description of that condition, if it previously contained a code.

So that for the first row in the above example, it would return the full description of `J` instead of the character value.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM MainTable
    LEFT JOIN Conditions AS C1 ON
        MainTable.Condition_1 = C1.Condition_Code
    LEFT JOIN Conditions AS C2 ON
        MainTable.Condition_2 = C2.Condition_Code
    LEFT JOIN Conditions AS C3 ON
        MainTable.Condition_3 = C3.Condition_Code
```

...however, I get a `missing operator in query expression` error.

`P.S.` It was tough to create the title for this one, since my database experience is limited, so if anyone has a better title, feel free to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly than maybe something like this would do the trick:

```
SELECT 
  (
    SELECT FIRST(Condition_Description) FROM Conditions C1 WHERE MT.Condition_1 = C1.Condition_Code  
  ) as C1_Description,
  (
    SELECT FIRST(Condition_Description) FROM Conditions C2 WHERE MT.Condition_2 = C2.Condition_Code  
  ) as C2_Description,
  (
    SELECT FIRST(Condition_Description) FROM Conditions C3 WHERE MT.Condition_3 = C3.Condition_Code  
  ) as C3_Description
FROM MainTable as MT
```

P.s. Not sure what is syntax of first function in access. Also Conditions table design is not very elegant :)

Comment: Going to test it out and get back to you.  Not my database, so.... yeah.  I'm just stuck with pulling data from it so that I can work on it.

Comment: Tested and it worked flawlessly.  Thank you so much for your help.